# Pandas Creating a single list from a column containing a list of objects

Tags: python, pandas

In some data I import into Pandas I have the following;

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "[{'id':102, 'name': 'A'}, {'id':103, 'name': 'B'}, {'id':104, 'name': 'C'}]" |

What I am wondering is if there is a good way of taking this structure and making a data frame as follows;

| ID | names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['A','B','C'] |

outputting a list of the names.

I was thinking to write a function and calling this on the dataframe - but I wondered if there was a better way I dont know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Data` contains string representation of a list of dict, you have to evaluate the content to transform it as a real list of dict. It can be done with `ast.literal_eval` then `explode` your Series to extract the `name` key. Finally, group by index to aggregate data:

```
import ast

df['Names'] = (df['Data'].map(ast.literal_eval).explode().str['name']
                         .groupby(level=0).agg(list))
print(df)

# Output:
   ID                                               Data      Names
0   1  [{'id':102, 'name': 'A'}, {'id':103, 'name': '...  [A, B, C]
```

If `Data` already contains a list of dict, you can safety remove `.map(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast

data = {'ID': [1], 'Data': ['[{"id":102, "name": "A"}, {"id":103, "name": "B"}, {"id":104, "name": "C"}]']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Parse the 'Data' column and extract the 'name' column
df = ( df.groupby(by='ID')
         .apply(lambda row: pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(row['Data'][0]))['name'].tolist() )
         ).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'names'})

print(df)
```

```
   ID            names
0   1  ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to pull the dict value from each dict in the list and create a new list:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID':'1','Data':"[{'id':102, 'name': 'A'}, {'id':103, 'name': 'B'}, {'id':104, 'name': 'C'}]"}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=[0])
df = df.assign(
        names=lambda dataframe: dataframe['Data'].map(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in listA])
    )
```